# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS brightness isn't adjustable

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have MSI Modern 14 B4MW-410IN Notebook. Specs - Ryzen 5 Hexacore 4500U. Everything is working fine but I can't change brightness after installing Ubuntu on it (which also using nomodeset otherwise couldn't boot the system). Tried every tutorial but not working.

Comment: what did you do to perform brightness switch? from FN + keyboard button or using the battery icon at systray?

Comment: @MatthiasLenmher It doesn't matter. With `nomodeset` it couldn't possibly work.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, chinese car vendor =) !

Comment: @MatthiasLenmher It's brand ambassador ;) and our cars are global

Comment: @ChanganAuto Nice!. (ps: i understod we can't make offtopic here hehe. hope you have a nice day)

Comment: @MatthiasLenmher I have keys for controlling brightness i used that, icons also appeared that brightness is increasing/decreasing but nothing worked. Tried that slider from power in settings and from the control center in the top right nothing worked. Used some online solns like adding acpi_backligh=vendor and all sorts of things. Installed AMD drivers and installed them after installing them my pc didn't start. Now I've uninstalled ubuntu